# Getting a reference to the document containing the microdata where specific RDF knowledge came from

Tags: html, rdf, microdata, rdfa

I am extracting microdata from HTML pages and convert them to knowledge in RDF triples. Now I would like to have a back reference from the RDF knowledge to the HTML document where it came from.

Is there any established way to annotate the source document to the RDF knowledge that is extracted from HTML microdata?

Should there be no such thing, is there maybe something like this for RDFa to RDF extraction?

I imagine something like adding another triple to any subject that is extracted from the document like the following:

```
?subject microdata:wasExtractedFrom file:abc.html
```

Or even something more specific like:

```
?knowledge rdf:subject ?subject
?knowledge rdf:predicate ?predicate
?knowledge rdf:object ?object
?knowledge microdata:wasExtractedFrom file:abc.html
```

Comment: Plain *RDF reification* would be too verbose. *RDR* is less verbose, but also is less supported and doesn't allow to "abstract" from source. There other *provenance* approachs... [These people](http://webdatacommons.org/structureddata/2019-12/stats/stats.html) use *named graphs*.

Comment: I am still a beginner with RDF, could you explain a little bit more what they are doing there and where I can see examples?

Comment: they use so called quads `(s,p,o,g)` instead of triples `(s,p,o)` with `g` denoting a graph which could be the HTML file in your case. Clearly, you need some quad format like N-Quads or Trig to serialize such data

Comment: A more recent alternative is to use RDF*, although this isn't (yet) part of the standard and not supported by all RDF related tools

Comment: @UninformedUser What does the `g` stand for in these quads?

Comment: the "graph", see the concept of RDF datasets: https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-datasets/ - an RDF graph is a set of triples, an RDF dataset is a set of RDF graphs

Comment: @UninformedUser but if I have one graph per source file, is there a way to query irrespective of which graph the knowledge is in?

Comment: yes, sure - with SPARQL you can easily query all named graph data